# Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: insufficient account keys for instruction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, transactions, send-transaction, instructions

I cloned this repo: [solana-movie-program](https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-program) and deployed it on Solana Playground.

I also cloned [solana-movie-client](https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-client) and tried it but I get the error: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: insufficient account keys for instruction"

Also here are the logs:

```
[
    'Program AJBhcFoWMtxWpmtkjfftKpiBBxXnVKo7y4jFVpAfmfQQ invoke [1]',
    'Program log: process_instruction: AJBhcFoWMtxWpmtkjfftKpiBBxXnVKo7y4jFVpAfmfQQ: 3 accounts, data=[0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 66, 114, 97, 118, 101, 104, 101, 97, 114, 116, 57, 48, 54, 56, 57, 54, 46, 54, 53, 55, 48, 52, 49, 48, 54, 57, 53, 5, 13, 0, 0, 0, 65, 32, 103, 114, 101, 97, 116, 32, 109, 111, 118, 105, 101]',
    'Program log: Adding movie review...',
    'Program log: Title: Braveheart906896.6570410695',
    'Program log: Rating: 5',
    'Program log: Description: A great movie',
    'Program AJBhcFoWMtxWpmtkjfftKpiBBxXnVKo7y4jFVpAfmfQQ consumed 27607 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program AJBhcFoWMtxWpmtkjfftKpiBBxXnVKo7y4jFVpAfmfQQ failed: insufficient account keys for instruction'
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using code from the `starter` branch:
https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-program/tree/starter

That client code builds the instruction like this:
https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-client/blob/main/src/index.ts#L61

```
const instruction = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
        programId: programId,
        data: buffer,
        keys: [
            {
                pubkey: signer.publicKey,
                isSigner: true,
                isWritable: false
            },
            {
                pubkey: pda,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: true
            },
            {
                pubkey: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false
            }
        ]
    })
```

Which matches these three accounts in the starter branch:
https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-program/blob/starter/src/processor.rs#L53

```
let  initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; 
let  pda_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; 
let  system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
```

However, if you used the main branch, there's four accounts, which might be the cause for the error you're seeing:
https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-program/blob/main/src/processor.rs#L55

```
let initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
let pda_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
let pda_counter = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
```

Here is the written content for this example program (the branches are for different sections):
https://soldev.app/course

Comment: That is the correct answer. However I get the error: "RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length"